# Detect Price with xpath Efficiently

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I need to scan the page for price and extract it, i was thinking of detecting $ and extract the value after $. How can i do that using xpath?

Unfortunately different page has different format. Therefore i need it to be smart enough to detect $12 or $12.30

```
$price= $xpath->query("//??[@??]");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure you'll be able to do that in XPath alone, but you could first select text node that contain $, e.g. with an XPath expression like `.//text()[contains(., "$")]` and then write the price parsing logic in your application

Comment: Can you share the html that you are trying to get text from?

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 2.0, you could use:

```
//*[text()[contains(., '$')]]/substring-after(text(),'$')
```